# Finding the height of the flagpole

Tags: trigonometry

A ray of sunlight casts a shadow of a flagpole on the ground at an angle of depression of 58 degrees. If the length of the shadow is 3m shorter than the height of the flagpole, find the height of the flagpole.

I'm confused about the given problem above because I can't determine yet the length of the shadow, and also I'm stuck at the angle of depression, in which I supposed that it has to be the angle of elevation instead.

My solution:

$\sin\left(58^{\circ }\right)=\frac{x}{x-3}$

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQogo.jpg)

Comment: why $\sin$?  Have you made a picture?

Comment: It is tan, not sin.  Refer to my answer

Comment: when it says that the length of the shadow is 3m shorter than the flagpole, they mean the shadow from the base of the flagpole to where the edge of the shadow is? so the bottom adjacent side of the triangle?

Comment: i think it has to be tan as mentioned above and below, assuming the length of shadow is the distance from the base of the flagpole

Comment: The diagram is wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, we draw a flagpole, $x$m long.  Then we draw a shadow that is $x-3$m long.  Then the sun ray which casts the shadow connects the TOP of the pole and TOP of the shadow.  This means the angle formed by the hypotenuse (the sun ray) and the shadow is $58^o$.  Now we have $\tan  58^o=\frac{x}{x-3}$, giving us $x\tan  58^o-3\tan  58^o=x$.  We bring $x$ to one side, having $x\left(\tan  58^o-1\right)=3\tan  58^o$.  $x=7.997...=8.00\left(3sf\right)$.
[image]

Comment: but actually the shadow was said to have the angle of depression

Comment: Yes, the shadow is formed on the ground, and the line connecting the tip of it and the top of the pole forms the degree of 58 with the ground

Comment: @Xtravagant you could draw a diagram

Comment: i've posted my sketch

Comment: @Xtravagant  your diagram is wrong

Comment: @Xtravagant  I added an image

Comment: ok, it's now clear to me. thanks a lot